# Is there a way to power on remotely via SSH?

Tags: hard-drive, power-management, reboot, restart, remote-access

I'm new to Linux and get by with a few basic commands (SSH). I run minimserver on a raspberry pi running Ubuntu server. It works great!

Every night I use sudo poweroff (using an iOS app called Terminus). I do this more because I want to preserve the mounted USB HDD that stores my music. After Ubuntu power off, the HDD also switches off automatically which is my desired result. The problem is the server is in another part of the house and the next day I have to go to the server and restart it (I unplug the power from the Rpi and plug in again). This also starts up and mounts the USB HDD (as I successfully managed to configure auto mount at start up).

What I would like to achieve is to simply unmount and switch the HDD off remotely so that the next day I can just run sudo reboot (again remotely) to get the HDD powered up and running again. I tried using umount /mnt/music but this command doesn't switch the HDD off. Or if there is a remote way to switch on the Rpi but this doesn't seem technically possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Apologies for the long post. I hope I've made sense.

Answer (score 1):

If there is power to the Raspberry Pi then it is on, even if you have gone to "shutdown" in the OS - at which point it merely puts the OS into a state where it is ready to be turned off.  Remember old IBM computers where you'd go to shutdown in Windows and then you'd see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDCuU.jpg)?  There is no way I know of to remotely reboot the device from that state as the OS has unloaded all support for networking, etc.

HDDs can cope with running 24/7.  If you do not like the idea of running it 24/7 though, you can enable [auto spindown after a delay using hdparm](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/hdparm).  Note the warning about causing increased wear on the drive by spinning it down when it's not in use and spinning it up when it is.  At some point, spinning it down and then up against a certain number of times can be worse for it than the additional time you'd leave it spinning.

You can even manually spin down the HDD at any time with `hdparm -y`.  There is no need to manually spin it up then, as it will do so when something needs to read or write to it.

Caveat: support for spin down via hdparm can vary, and this is especially true for USB hard drives and enclosures.  Some support it, but there are even some USB hard drives that ignore all spin down commands and have their own in-built idle spindown.

Comment: also smartctl via smartmontools... I believe I was bitten by the same above-mentioned caveat once. If i remember correctly, you have to run it and see if the desired features are supported by your drive. `apt-get install smartmontools` and check the smartctl man pages. With that said, all of these suggestions and even the OP's goal is "considered" aggressive power management, which is thought to be worse-off for the drive.... there will likely be a sooner point of diminishing returns.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me with this. I realise now my question was not really a linux question. I think I will just leave the server running with the HDD attached since they can cope with that. Thanls again

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1284167), when the raspberry pi is off, it is not in a state to accept any instructions, so you can't use SSH to turn the device on.

One workaround for this is to connect the raspberry pi's power supply to a RF or smart outlet.

Comment: Wake-on-LAN, perhaps?

Comment: @chili555: No, Raspberry Pi doesn't support WOL.

Answer (score 1):

I see two possibilities:

1. **Wake-on-Lan**: in this case, you have to configure the raspberry to accept WOL requests.  This is merely a question of BIOS. Afterwards, you have to install a specific program on the computer you use to send a so-called 'magic packet' to your Raspberry.  Watch out: both devices must be connected on the same subnetwork because the protocol is not routable.
2. **Wake at**: Use a script (eventually a cronjob) to instruct your raspberry to wake-up at a certain date/time, before turning it off.

### Some details:

### For WOL:

on Ubuntu, use `etherwake`:

```
sudo apt-get install etherwake
```

To send a magic packet:

```
etherwake  AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF
```

where AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF is the MAC adress of your raspberry. It can be obtained as:

```
ping -c 4 server3 && arp -n
```

More details [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-send-wake-on-lan-wol-magic-packets.html)

### For Scripting

First you need to go into BIOS and make sure that the computer alarm is enabled to start at a given time.  For more info, please, see e.g. [this](https://www.wikihow.com/Automatically-Turn-On-a-Computer-at-a-Specified-Time).

Afterwards, it a a mere question of scripting.  Here is the script I use:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This program shuts down the PC and set a start time for next wake up
# Wake up is scheduled on next weekday at 6:00

# Setting wake-up alarm
springtime="+1 days 06:00"
echo 0 > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm
echo `date +%s -d "$springtime"`   > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm

/sbin/shutdown now
```